# Problema com urllib3 e API Twitter

Tags: python, twitter-api

Salve codeiros de plantão

Estou usando esse fonte para API twitter

https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI

Ao executar os exemplos da erro:

> File "stream_tweets.py", line 1, in 
>       from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import ReadTimeoutError, ProtocolError ImportError: cannot import name ReadTimeoutError

Alguém ja usou a api e sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que seu pacote `requests` está numa versão antiga. Você precisa fazer um `upgrade`. Esses pacotes usam `urllib3`. Na linha de comando, execute:

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

Ou, para fazer o upgrade de tudo que a API do Twitter usa, rode:

```
pip install TwitterAPI --upgrade
```

Uma vez que você está usando Python 2.7, talvez precisa de instalar o pip: `install pip`.